# Font face from file do not load during debug

Tags: javascript, font-face

A font from file is not loading during debug. Only at the end of execution it is displayed. This is causing troubles to calculate precisely the size of my divs.

[image]

[image]

I wrote a fiddle just to show the code, because the font is paid.

```js
function test(){
    var body = document.getElementsByTagName("BODY")[0];
    var div = document.createElement("div");
    div.innerHTML = "The font is not Kohinnor in debug";
    body.appendChild(div);
    console.log("end");
}
```

```css
@font-face {
  font-family: KohinoorBangla;
  src: url("KohinoorBangla.ttc");
}

body{
    font-family:KohinoorBangla;
    font-size: 20px;
    color:red;
    margin: 20mm;
}
```

```html
<html>
<head>
    <script src="script.js"></script>
    <link href="style.css" rel="stylesheet">
</head>
<body>
<script>test()</script>
</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The solution I found was to install the font locally and then load it, as I am creating an HTML to create a PDF document on server only for internal purposes.

```
<style>
@font-face {
  font-family: 'Kohinoor Bangla';
  src: local('Kohinoor Bangla');
}

body{
    font-family:'Kohinoor Bangla';
}

</style>
```